# How do I copy writeablebitmap to clipboard from an elevated trust silverlight application using P/Invoke?

Tags: pinvoke, clipboard, silverlight-5.0

I've got a silverlight 5 application that is running elevated trust in-browser. This allows us to do things that wouldn't ordinarily be possible in silverlight like having more access to the clipboard via P/Invoke.

What I need to be able to do is copy controls to the clipboard so they could be pasted into Word or Outlook. I can convert the controls to an image via WriteableBitmap but copying the data to the clipboard is something I'm having issues with.

Calling code:

```
  WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(elements[0], new ScaleTransform() { ScaleX = 1.0, ScaleY = 1.0 });
  int[] p = bmp.Pixels;
  int len = p.Length * 4;
  byte[] result = new byte[len];
  Buffer.BlockCopy(p, 0, result, 0, len);

  CopyToClipboardViaPInvoke(result, ClipboardFormat.CF_BITMAP);
```

Copy function:

```
private void CopyToClipboardViaPInvoke(byte[] data, ClipboardFormat format)
{
    IntPtr p = IntPtr.Zero;
    if (Native.OpenClipboard(p))
    {
        GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        try
        {
            Native.EmptyClipboard();
            IntPtr result = Native.SetClipboardData(format, pointer);
        }
        finally
        {
            Native.CloseClipboard();
            pinnedArray.Free();
        }
    }
}
```

The result says it's successful, but paste does nothing. `IsClipboardFormatAvailable` also states that the format is available on the clipboard. I've also tried various ClipboardFormat inputs and other methods of converting the control to an image without any luck.

### Update 1

Thanks to suggestions from user629926 I've got what I think is a little closer but I'm still missing something.

```
  Native.EmptyClipboard();
  IntPtr bmp = IntPtr.Zero;
  GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
  IntPtr bmpPointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
  Native.StartupInput sin = new Native.StartupInput() { GdiplusVersion = 1 };
  Native.StartupOutput sout = new Native.StartupOutput();
  IntPtr gdip = IntPtr.Zero;

  int startup = Native.GdiplusStartup(out gdip, ref sin, out sout);
  int created = Native.GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0(width, height, width * 4, 0x0026200A, bmpPointer, out bmp);
  IntPtr result = Native.SetClipboardData(format, bmp);

  Native.DeleteObject(bmp);
  Native.GdiplusShutdown(ref gdip);
```

Comment: Not sure , but you are sending raw pixel data to clipboard, but the other side can't interpret them w/o bitmap header. Try converting it ot to Bitmap and pass bitmap.GetHBitamp().

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking the problem was. However, I'm using Silverlight and don't have access to Bitmap.GetHBitmap()

Answer (score 0):

Use GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0 to get HBitmap from you array and pass it to clipboard and the DeleteObject to free it.

```
[DllImport("gdiplus.dll")]
static extern int GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0(int width, int height, int stride, int format, IntPtr scan0, out IntPtr bitmap); 
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
```

Comment: I changed to call: GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0(width, height, width * 4, 0x0026200A, bmpPointer, out bmp); 

No luck. It's returning with"18" and I haven't been able to find what that means.

Comment: Just to know I new used gdi+ directly. Error code is GdiplusNotInitialized. It seem that you need to use this before any other call http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Probably just need to construct and Bitmap and the .NET will initialize gdi+ for you.

Comment: Not sure you could try to test it in local WinForms environment and use Bitmap.FromHBitmap() to check if you got the good bitmap object.

Comment: Do you call OpenClipoard() before doing all this?